# MEAN STACK ,"Error in Postman : Username or password is invalid! "

Tags: node.js, angular, database, postman, mean-stack

I am beginner in mean stack development and i am trying to run "api/users/login" in Postman it is showing "Username or password is invalid!". And when i am run "register/users/register" i got "user is already exist". How can i solve it.

**register :**

[image: register]

**login :**

[image: login]

**Here is my code :**

**user.router.ts**

```
import {Router} from 'express';
import { sample_users } from '../data';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import { User, UserModel } from '../models/user.model';
import { HTTP_BAD_REQUEST } from '../constants/http_status';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
const router = Router();

router.get("/seed", asyncHandler(
  async (req, res) => {
     const usersCount = await UserModel.countDocuments();
     if(usersCount> 0){
       res.send("Seed is already done!");
       return;
     }
 
     await UserModel.create(sample_users);
     res.send("Seed Is Done!");
 }
 ))

router.post("/login", asyncHandler(
  async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = await req.body;
    console.log(req.body.email + " userEmail");
    console.log(req.body.password + "  userPassword" );

    const user = await UserModel.findOne({email});
    console.log(user?.password);
  
     if(user && (await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password))) {
      res.send(generateTokenReponse(user));
     }
     else{
       res.status(HTTP_BAD_REQUEST).send("Username or password is invalid!");
     }
  
  }
))
  
router.post('/register', asyncHandler(
  async (req, res) => {
    const {name, email, password, address} = await req.body;
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({email});
    if(user){
      res.status(HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
      .send('User is already exist, please login!');
      return;
    }

    const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    const newUser:User = {
      id:'',
      name,
      email: email.toLowerCase(),
      password: encryptedPassword,
      address,
      isAdmin: false
    }

    const dbUser = await UserModel.create(newUser);
    res.send(generateTokenReponse(dbUser));
  }
))

  const generateTokenReponse = (user : User) => {
    const token = jwt.sign({
      id: user.id, email:user.email, isAdmin: user.isAdmin
    },process.env.JWT_SECRET!,{
      expiresIn:"30d"
    });
  
    return {
      id: user.id,
      email: user.email,
      name: user.name,
      address: user.address,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      token: token
    };
  }
  

  export default router;
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { USER_LOGIN_URL, USER_REGISTER_URL } from '../shared/constants/urls';
import { IUserLogin } from '../shared/interfaces/IUserLogin';
import { IUserRegister } from '../shared/interfaces/IUserRegister';
import { User } from '../shared/models/User';

const USER_KEY = 'User';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private userSubject =
  new BehaviorSubject<User>(this.getUserFromLocalStorage());
  public userObservable:Observable<User>;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private toastrService:ToastrService) {
    this.userObservable = this.userSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public get currentUser():User{
    return this.userSubject.value;
  }

  login(userLogin:IUserLogin):Observable<User>{
    return this.http.post<User>(USER_LOGIN_URL, userLogin).pipe(
      tap({
        next: (user) =>{
          this.setUserToLocalStorage(user);
          this.userSubject.next(user);
          this.toastrService.success(
            `Welcome to Foodmine ${user.name}!`,
            'Login Successful'
          )
        },
        error: (errorResponse) => {
          this.toastrService.error(errorResponse.error, 'Login Failed');
        }
      })
    );
  }

  register(userRegiser:IUserRegister): Observable<User>{
    return this.http.post<User>(USER_REGISTER_URL, userRegiser).pipe(
      tap({
        next: (user) => {
          this.setUserToLocalStorage(user);
          this.userSubject.next(user);
          this.toastrService.success(
            `Welcome to the Foodmine ${user.name}`,
            'Register Successful'
          )
        },
        error: (errorResponse) => {
          this.toastrService.error(errorResponse.error,
            'Register Failed')
        }
      })
    )
  }


  logout(){
    this.userSubject.next(new User());
    localStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY);
    window.location.reload();
  }

  private setUserToLocalStorage(user:User){
    localStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, JSON.stringify(user));
  }

  private getUserFromLocalStorage():User{
    const userJson = localStorage.getItem(USER_KEY);
    if(userJson) return JSON.parse(userJson) as User;
    return new User();
  }
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page',
  templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-page.component.css']
})
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm!:FormGroup;
  isSubmitted = false;
  returnUrl = '';
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder
    , private userService:UserService,
     private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,
     private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email:['', [Validators.required,Validators.email]],
      password:['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.returnUrl = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams.returnUrl;
  }

  get fc(){
    return this.loginForm.controls;
  }

  submit(){
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if(this.loginForm.invalid) return;

    this.userService.login({email:this.fc.email.value,
       password: this.fc.password.value}).subscribe(() => {
         this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl);
       });
  }

}
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private userService:UserService, private router:Router){

  }
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    if(this.userService.currentUser.token) return true;

    this.router.navigate(['/login'], {queryParams:{returnUrl: state.url}})
    return false;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it turns out nothing was wrong in my code. I only had to switch the Body to x-www-form-urlencoded in Postman.
[image]